# store public key in variable php

Tags: php, openssl, coding-style, public-key

I have a public key which I would like to store in a variable as string, for example :

```
$public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDH82E/Dn37torKz/vhAkpji9ZS
HCyfM7JuXCbh70F75Zh2/rEVvz38yNf6f01DNXiSpzO5eTmoXD7Blsb635AOjYbl
X/WljpFbwQ2QUUDlNDAslrqXYlMzht2MCq/pjtGgk0zJx6i+HjFyV7mebeePQY/x
NOzMpmy/Ke3u+SSHRwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

I would like to have something like this

```
$public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
              MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDH82E/Dn37torKz/vhAkpji9ZS
              HCyfM7JuXCbh70F75Zh2/rEVvz38yNf6f01DNXiSpzO5eTmoXD7Blsb635AOjYbl
              X/WljpFbwQ2QUUDlNDAslrqXYlMzht2MCq/pjtGgk0zJx6i+HjFyV7mebeePQY/x
              NOzMpmy/Ke3u+SSHRwIDAQAB
              -----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

For the moment, it fails because the key is no more valid because spaces with indentation

How to deal with break lines and indentation?

Comment: What do you mean _"deal with"_???

Comment: I've edited my post, please see what i would like to have as final result

Comment: OK, just do it the way you did in the second example.

Comment: yes but when executing, it fails because the key is no more valid because spaces with indentation

Comment: You might also need ***`\n`*** for each new line OpenSSL's PEM parser is lame, and it fails without them (IIRC).

Comment: The newlines must be there, after 64 characters each in the PEM format. That’s where they are in your original string, and that’s what the standards say. They can certainly be in the form of a literal `\n`. They don’t need to be there as actual line breaks in your editor. Just remember to wrap your string in double quotes and not single quotes. See also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19043/can-i-remove-newlines-in-a-public-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the heredoc statement to align the key.

```
$str = <<<'KEY'
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDH82E/Dn37torKz/vhAkpji9ZS
HCyfM7JuXCbh70F75Zh2/rEVvz38yNf6f01DNXiSpzO5eTmoXD7Blsb635AOjYbl
X/WljpFbwQ2QUUDlNDAslrqXYlMzht2MCq/pjtGgk0zJx6i+HjFyV7mebeePQY/x
NOzMpmy/Ke3u+SSHRwIDAQAB
KEY;
```

Or concat strings:

```
$str = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDH82E/Dn37torKz/vhAkpji9ZS'.
       'HCyfM7JuXCbh70F75Zh2/rEVvz38yNf6f01DNXiSpzO5eTmoXD7Blsb635AOjYbl'.
       'X/WljpFbwQ2QUUDlNDAslrqXYlMzht2MCq/pjtGgk0zJx6i+HjFyV7mebeePQY/x'.
       'NOzMpmy/Ke3u+SSHRwIDAQAB';
```

Other then that, use functions to remove the additional symbols like linebreaks and spaces or.. store the key in a file and use `file_get_contents()` Secure that file with chmod or store it outside the root directory of your web server.

Alternatively, you can create a file like key.php:

```
<?php
  return 'yourkey';
?>
```

And then you can store it in a var like so:

```
$var = include 'key.php';
```

This way, code pollution is put back to a minimum.

Comment: Ok will try it. I can't use file_get_contents() ^^

Comment: Added an alternative way for `file_get_contents()`. However usually only external url's are blocked. Not internal files for this function.

Comment: can't use your second option. I will store the key as constant in my class